# value in combobox C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

i have combobox in datagrid (sourse in mysql (web))
how i can get value in select?

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged".........
```

c#

```
private void status_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this here 
}
```

how???

and how to get the value in another column, but in this line?

```
column_one   column_two

   value1      value2
```

Is change to `column two`, how getting column one?

**update:**
my items

```
<ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBoxItem>New</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Cancel</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox.Items>
```

Comment: How are you defining columns in datagrid in XAML?

Comment: `<ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBoxItem>New</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Cancel</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox.Items>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution?

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox"  SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged" ... />

private void status_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var value = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;
}
```

If you need to get value in other column but in same row, you can make new event for cells of your DataGrid and take needed value something like that

```
DataGrid.Item[var1,var2]
```

Where var1 is a row number and var2 column number.

When I have to use Datagrid with complex cells, i save row and column number of each element (ComboBox in your case) in .Tag property, and eject it for determine cell number.

Comment: Sorry, it was solution for WinForms.

Comment: For using data in other column but same row you need this
`(TextBlock)myDataGrid.Columns[number].GetCellContent(myDataGrid.SelectedItem).Text = "Hello";`
, where "number" - number of interesting column in DataGrid

Comment: which value are selected in DataGrid.SelectionMode?

Comment: Sorry, not in SelectionMode; i was mean SelectionUnit.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells.aspx
SelectedItems for get selected rows, and SelectedCells for get selected cells.

Comment: Maybe using of DataGrid.SelectedCells[NumberOfYourColumn] is a right way. And it have Content property for getting controls in cell

Answer (score 0):

You can access your combo box by name.

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged" Name="myComboBox" ... />
private void status_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string value = myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: myComboBox, i dont have this name

Comment: I showed you how, look at my answer, you have to name your combo box in xaml. Choose any name.

Comment: OK, that is just an idea, play around a little. Debug and look into selected item, also look into SelectedValue property.